Started new job but want to find a new one
I started a new job about 2.5 months ago, and it's not a great fit. I'm going to apply for new jobs, but I don't know if I should add this current job to my resume or just keep my last job as the most recent one. I probably wouldn't get any responses if they see that I just started a new job, but I also wouldn't want to lie if they ask what I've been doing since I left my previous job. The field is IT in a school district.

"I probably wouldn't get any responses if they see that I just started a new job" What evidence do you have for this statement?

Are any of the answers to these questions of use to you? https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/117833/started-a-new-job-a-week-ago-i-want-to-leave      https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/150476/started-new-job-and-dont-like-it

There really is no way no to include it. If it was a 2 or 3 weeks it would be easier to leave off.
It is a valid reason to say that a job isn't a good fit. Be ready to be upfront and not act as if you are trying to hide it.
Of course, don't leave the current job without getting a new job.

Don't try to hide it.
It doesn't look good in the background check. Because, "why are you hiding it?" What did you do there that made you want to hide that job from your resume... Its a school, so were you fired because you slept with parents? misbehaved with students?... It makes people guesss why you tried to hide it.
So keep it on the resume, but have a good anser for why you are leaving. "Not a good fit" is an acceptable reason.
Having a single job that you didn't stay that long at, is not a red flag. Not all jobs are a good fit, and you don't always realize it until after you started working there. A lot of us have started jobs that just didn't work out.
That being said multiple short term jobs (unless you were a contractor..though then you list your job as 'contractor/self employed') is a red flag. Because it makes you look flakey

Whether or not it is a problem depends on the context. I don't know how many jobs you have held in the past, nor what 'not right for me' means, but if your interviewers can visualize themselves making the same decision as you did or see it as one failure in a successful string, it isn't a problem.
If that's less clear, you want to hide or minimize it. I guess nobody wants to publicly be the one telling you to lie, but I've seen a half dozen people paper over a bad job (sometimes the one where I worked with them) by extending the end date at the previous employer.
In your situation - given you work for a school in summer recess, try to minimize the impact without lying by pointing out that you stayed until the end of the school year but decided not to sign up for the next one. Also if you can, offer a generous advance notice - say three weeks - and mention that when you discuss this situation.
Last, and also least, I assume that you've already decided that you cannot stick it out. But can you work with your current employer to change up what you don't like? Transfer departments or work for a different boss? This is the best option for your career. Some employers will compromise rather than lose an employee. And if you're planning to leave anyway, you aren't risking too much if you try.
